# Where is var/lock in Magento 1.9?

Tags: stock, reindex, stock-status, magento-1.9

I get the error "Stock Status Index process is working now. Please try run this process later." when trying to reindex.  Other answers say to clear var/lock/.

where is var/lock in 1.9?

Answer (score 3):

The `var/locks/` (note the "s") directory is created whenever you start an indexing process. Magento writes out a lock file to this directory. Removing the lock files may resolve issues with reindexing.

Like in previous Magento versions, in Magento 1.9 you can find this directory here:

`[your Magento install dir]/var/`

If the directory isn't there, Magento hasn't created it. If this is the case, then you should look for other solutions for fixing the reindexing issue.

Maybe your `var` directory doesn't have the right permissions. Magento needs sufficient permissions to be able to create the `var/locks` directory and write out the lock files. Try setting permissions for `var` to (at least) **755**.

If this doesn't help, maybe you can reindex via SSH or try restarting your webserver.

Comment: Hi and thanks.  Permissions are set OK, I'll look for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It was quite difficult to find out where are these locks are saving.

By default Magento saving the locks in the database, in these case, you may not find any /var/locks folder on your server.

Debugging further I reached in the file  app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Helper\Mysql4.php

Run these queries in your MySQL console

```
 SELECT IS_USED_LOCK('dev_tts_magento.index_process_3') //this is for catalog url rewrite
```

The same way you can release, lock from here.

Find an impressive blog out there

<strike>http://magehero.com/posts/327/useful-mysql-commands-for-debugging-magento-reindex-locks</strike>.

http://tutsplanet.com/var-lock-release-lock-magento-1-9-1436/

Comment: Link is not working, this one is:
https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder/24a881dc6ef72a2e1c5e

Answer (score 0):

in magento 1.9 the index lock in database is

select IS_USED_LOCK('*database*.index_process_7');

to release a lock

SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('*database*.index_process_7');

there are different number index_process_*number* for different index process.
the process id number can be found from admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Direct access in DB is the "index_process" table. I had to delete one that was still running from a removed plug-in